# java with hibernate

Tags: java

I have a code which gets the date from Database from which I took year as below code:

```
 Date expiryDate=dataMgr.getDate(); 
 int validity=2;    
 expiryDate.setYear(expiryDate.getYear() + validity); 
 // some piece of code
 tx.commit();
```

i am using hibernate to fetch from Database. everything is working    fine but the problem is after commiting ....The DB year    from which i    took the date (dataMgr.getDate()) also gets changed i    dont know why    ?? can some one clear me out???

For example, form the above code `expiryDate:4/21/2012` (from Database). After commiting it gets changed to `4/21/2014` in DB which should not happen?? 
I haven't used that corresponding object any where or updating any where ???

help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects are in `Persistent state` in a single `transaction`. Moreover, both `expiryDate` and `dateMgr.getDate` are referring to same object.

Instead of getting reference, get clone of object

```
Date expiryDate=dataMgr.getDate().clone();
```

I am not sure about the syntax, please check that.